# Use PayPal Python SDK to automate the payment execution for an direct payment link

Tags: python, paypal, sdk, paypal-rest-sdk

what I want to do is to use the [PayPal-Python-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK) to automate the payment execution. For that I just want to paste in a direct payment link, that I receive as a normal user from PayPal of a company for example. So when I receive this link that mostly look like this https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart?flowlogging_id=XXXXXXXXXX#/checkout/openButton
I want to put this into my python code to execute my payment automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal checkout pages are only designed and intended to work for end users loading them in an interactive web browser/user agent. If you attempt to fill out paypal.com forms "automatically", this will result in those payer accounts and cards being banned in the PayPal system, and possibly your PayPal business account being closed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I thought so but was hoping that there is a workaround.

Comment: It would help to know more about what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps you are looking for something like the Payouts service, which is an add-on account feature https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts